# Share multiple videos on one page onto facebook wall

Tags: facebook, video, share

I have a website where there are multiple videos on a single page and like to add a button to share each video separately onto Facebook wall and be capable of playing each video inside the Facebook timeline.

I understand if there was only one video to share on the page, it is as easy as adding Open Graph tags to the head of the page to make this happen. But this will obviously not work for me since there are multiple videos on the page with share to facebook buttons on each video.

Does anyone know how I can go about making this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Its simple put the Facebook/Twitter/Google/etc buttons onto a separate page and use an iframe to put it on the main page. You can use php to automatically create the "share" pages.

I did it for a site I'm making you can see it here - http://www.lftv.com.br/index.php